# How to detect if a foreign key has been added in a mysql stored procedure?

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I have tried the following, but for some reason the `@check` parameter gets set to the value of the constraint I'm trying to check for even if the constraint doesn't exist.

Any ideas why?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddForeignKey(
    IN constraint_name varchar(64),
    IN foreign_key_column_name varchar(64),
    IN table_name varchar(64),
    IN database_name varchar(64),
    IN foreign_table_key_name varchar(64),
    IN foreign_table_name varchar(64))

BEGIN
    set @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', database_name, '.', table_name,
            ' ADD CONSTRAINT ', constraint_name,
                ' FOREIGN KEY (', foreign_key_column_name, ')'
                ' REFERENCES ', foreign_table_name, ' (', foreign_table_key_name, ');' ) ;

    set @dbname = database_name;

    set @fkname = constraint_name;

    set @check = '';

    SELECT 
        CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INTO
        @check
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE
       CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @dbname
    AND
       CONSTRAINT_NAME   = @fkname
    AND
       CONSTRAINT_TYPE   = 'FOREIGN KEY'
    LIMIT 1;

    IF @check != @fkname
    THEN
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
    ELSE
        insert into errors(message) values (CONCAT ( 'Check: ', @check, ' DB:', @dbname, ' FK:', @fkname, ' Could not execute statement: ',  @sql));
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/huwJ99DrjLbaLPqKCvcBhB/0).

Comment: I am not using MySQL as the root user. I am also using MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only compare the column `CONSTRAINT_NAME` that is not enough to prevent a foreign key duplicate creation.

You must add `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table and add more columns to compare.

Also I changed the variable names to avoid unnecessary variable names:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddForeignKey(
    IN p_constraint_name varchar(64),
    IN foreign_key_column_name varchar(64),
    IN p_table_name varchar(64),
    IN p_database_name varchar(64),
    IN foreign_table_key_name varchar(64),
    IN foreign_table_name varchar(64))

BEGIN
    set @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', p_database_name, '`.`', p_table_name,
        '` ADD CONSTRAINT `', p_constraint_name,
            '` FOREIGN KEY (`', foreign_key_column_name, '`)'
            ' REFERENCES `', foreign_table_name, '` (`', foreign_table_key_name, '`);' ) ;

    set @check = '';

    SELECT 
        TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        INTO @check
    FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
            ON  TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
              AND TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME = REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME
              AND TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME = REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME

    WHERE
    TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA =  p_database_name
        AND TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME   =  p_constraint_name
        AND TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE   = 'FOREIGN KEY'
    AND TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME = p_table_name
        and REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = foreign_table_name
    LIMIT 1;

    IF @check <> p_constraint_name
    THEN
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
    ELSE
        insert into errors(message) values (CONCAT ( 'Check: ', @check, ' DB:', @dbname, ' FK:', 
        @fkname, ' Could not execute statement: ',  @sql));
    END IF;

END
```

Comment: I don't believe you've answered my question. I will make the changes you've suggested and see if anything is effected, but I doubt it. You make fair points about terser SQL and a more thorough check, but those aren't the problems I'm having. Also, the insert in the ELSE condition will fail.

Comment: Not really sure how, but this seems to have fixed it.